# DATE_SUB syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a cron job to delete records that are more than an hour old and the field 'activated' = 0 but I keep getting a message to check my syntax.

```
$sql = "DELETE * FROM user WHERE dateCreated < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
AND activated = 0";
```

I'm getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM user WHERE dateCreated < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND activated =' at line 118

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which "syntax", SQL or PHP?

Comment: The message says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM user WHERE dateCreated < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND activated =' at line 118

Comment: Hopefully you can see how including that type of information in your question is crucial in order for people to understand and help you.

Comment: yup, I can see that now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE FROM`, omit the `*`.  Your comment follow up helped.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the `*`. That's for `SELECT`s, not `DELETE`s.

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE dateCreated < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND activated = 0
```